# How to display button over a Ad Mediator in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, button, windows-phone-8, canvas

I use in the application [Ad Mediator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn864359.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I need to add a button(see example)
[image: example]

I tried to use the Canvas and Canvas.Zindex. But then does not display advertising. Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Can we see your `xaml` pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just embed it in a panel like `Grid` so it just follows the DOM. Something like (in pseudo);

```
<Grid>
  <AdMediator/>
  <Button/>
</Grid>
```